# codeigniter strange image path issue

Tags: image, codeigniter, path

I am trying to do an application with CI. My problem is that when I load my main page, I can see my images (path is base_url/controller). However, if I click one of the links (through controller/function/seg) and get the query data from my database, the images become broken link (same view page but the path is now "base_url/controller/function/seg). my images folder is outside of the application folder and I am not sure what's going on. Thanks for the help.

My code: Controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller
{

    public $results;

    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('project_query');
        $this->results=$this->project_query->query();



    }       


    public function index()  //show my main page
    {
        $data['view']='main_page_V';
        $data['result']=$this->results->result();
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

    }

    public function search($city='') {   //after user click the link
        $this->results=$this->project_query->query($city);
        $data['view']='main_page_V';
        $data['result']=$this->results->result();
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

    }
}
```

part of my view page:

```
    //this image become broken link after user click the links 
    <div id='title'><img src='images/title.png' title='index Picture'/></div>


    <section>

    //this image become broken link after user click the links 
    <div id='index'><img src='images/title.jpg' title='index Picture'/></div>

    <nav>

        <ul>
            <li id=browser ><a href=#></a>
                <div id='submenu1'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?= anchor('main/search/salis','City Of Salisbury');?></li>
                        <li><?= anchor('main/search/fruit','City Of Fruitland');?></li>
                        <li><?= anchor('main/search/wicom','Wicomico County');?></li>
                        <li><?= anchor('main/search/other','Other Municipality ');?></li>
                        <li><?= anchor('main/search/all',"Show All (<span class='red'>Long Processing Time</span>)");?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li id=user_management><a href=#></a></li>
            <li id=log_out><a href=#> </a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

My model

```
class project_query extends CI_Model
    {
        #   internal variables


        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function query($city='salis')
        {
            $this->db->select('job_number,street_number, city ,map, subdivision_project');
            $this->db->like('city',$city);
            $result=$this->db->get('jobs');
            return $result;
        } 


    }
```

Comment: Try adding a leading slash to the image URLs

Comment: Thanks Tim, but seems like it works after i add <?=base_url();?> to my image path =>  <div id='index'><img src='<?=base_url();?>/images/title.jpg' title='index Picture'/></div. Still don't know why, hope someone can answer me. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim is right.  Without a leading slash (i.e. `/images/...`), the path is relative to the current URI, which will rarely be what you want.  No need for the overhead of a `base_url()` function call.  Just put the leading slash in there...

Comment: well..i did try to put a leading slash first. still not working. I had to pus base_url function. Anyone knows why?

Comment: If the leading slash does not work, likely your app is in a sub directory? The leading slash will resolve to the domain. If you app is one level below, this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having to add base_url each time, I have to wonder if your $config['base_url'] value is set to as CI bases all directory relationships on that URL.

Comment: well. my base_url is htt p://localhost/mysite/. Does it help?

Comment: Are your images stored in your site's root? e.g. htt p://localhost/mysite/images/